# How can I generate new set of smiling faces at random position after user click on extra smiling face?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get the smiley faces to generate in new random position by putting the function delete_all_children() at appropriate locations, but everytime, it won't run properly. Instead, if I ignore the randomized location after finding the extra picture, the game runs properly but it is a build up from existing smiley faces, which makes the game easier.

I want the new faces to generate in random location.

Please help!

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Matching Game - Smiling :)</title>

    <style>
        div, img {position: absolute;}
        div {width: 500px; height: 500px;}
        #rightSide {left: 500px; border-left: 1px solid black}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            var numberOfFace = 5;
            var count = 0;
            var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        function generateFaces() {

            var theLeftSide = document.getElementById('leftSide');
            var theRightSide = document.getElementById('rightSide');

            while (count < numberOfFace) {
            var top_random = (Math.random() * 400);
            var left_random = (Math.random() * 400);

            var smiling_face = document.createElement("img");
            smiling_face.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
            smiling_face.style.top = Math.floor(top_random) + "px";
            smiling_face.style.left = Math.floor(left_random) + "px";
            theLeftSide.appendChild(smiling_face);
            count ++;
            };

            leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
            theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);

            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            numberOfFace += 5;
            generateFaces();
            };

            theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
            alert("Game Over!");
            theBody.onclick = null;
            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
            };

            function delete_all_children() {
                var theNode = document.getElementById("theBody");
                while (theNode.firstChild) {
                    theNode.removeChild(theNode.firstChild);
                };
            };

            };


    </script>
</head>

<body onload="generateFaces()">
    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
    <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left!</p>
    <div id="leftSide"></div>
    <div id="rightSide"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From a short look, you don't have an element with `theBody` as its' `ID`

Comment: From the code posted there is no element with the attribute ID "theBody" but instead a variable called theBody which contains the body element so theNode = theBody am I guessing right?

Comment: Thanks you guys are right :)